# Proof that $V\odot W\cong W\odot V$ for vector spaces $V$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I've read a proof that the algebraic tensor product of vector spaces is 'commutative' in the sense that $V\odot W\cong W\odot V$. Although I believe I have managed to prove this by showing that they both have same dimension, therefore are isomorphic, this is not a 'constructive' proof in the sense that it not provide an explicit example of a linear isomorphism.

In Appendix T of Wegge-Olsen's book *$K$-Theory and $C^*$-Algebras*, this is proved by showing that there is a linear isomorphism $\varphi:V\odot W\to W\odot V$ with $\varphi(v\otimes w)=w\otimes v$ for all $v\in V, w\in W$.

The only way I see of doing this is by using a result which is later on in the book i.e. proving injectivity via $$f\otimes e=f'\otimes e'\Rightarrow e=e',f=f'\Rightarrow e\otimes f=e'\otimes f',$$ where $e,e'\in E$, $f,f'\in F$ and $E,F$ are bases of $V,W$, respectively.

But that result uses commutativity, so this approach would be circular. Is there another way of doing this?

In other words, without using the result that when $\sum e_i\otimes f_i=0$ and $f_i$ lin. indep. implies $e_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Well, it has an inverse function. There's also the detail of checking $\phi$ is well-defined in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have constructed a linear map $\phi:V\otimes W \to W\otimes V$ with the property that for all $v\in V, w\in W$, we have $\phi(v\otimes w) = w\otimes v$. Similarly, construct a linear map $\psi:W\otimes V\to V\otimes W$ with the property that for all $v\in V, w\in W$, we have $\psi(w\otimes v)=v\otimes w$.

Then, it is easy to see that for such "pure tensors", $\phi\circ \psi$ and $\psi\circ \phi$ are the identity map (on appropriate spaces). But in general, an element of $V\otimes W$ is a finite sum of pure tensors, so $\psi\circ \phi = \text{id}_{V\otimes W}$. Similarly, an arbitrary element of $W\otimes V$ is a finite sum of pure tensors hence $\phi\circ \psi=\text{id}_{W\otimes V}$. This directly shows $\phi,\psi$ are inverse isomorphisms.

So, really, all we're using is that pure tensors span the whole tensor product, and that if a linear map is equal to identity when restricted to a spanning set, then it is equal to identity on the whole space. In general when trying to prove isomorphisms involving tensor products, I think it is much easier to construct the maps in both directions (and very often this is almost immediate by the universal property of tensor products) rather than proving injectivity/surjectivity directly, because often times we don't really understand the particular elements of the tensor product well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general proof (for tensor products of modules over commutative rings) using only the universal property.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$

Consider the bilinear maps $\phi_1\colon V\times W\to W\odot V$, $(v,w)\mapsto w\otimes v$ and $\phi_2\colon W\times V\to V\odot W$, $(w,v)\mapsto v\otimes w$.

By the universal property of the tensor products, you get $\tilde\phi_1\colon V\odot W\to W\odot V$ and $\tilde\phi_2\colon W\odot V\to V\odot W$. Now, it is easy to check that the maps in question satisfy $\tilde\phi_2\tilde\phi_1(v\otimes w)=v\otimes w$ and $\tilde\phi_1\tilde\phi_2(w\otimes v)=w\otimes v$ for any $v,w$.

On the other hand, by the universal property, there is a unique map $V\odot W\to V\odot W$ with $v\otimes w\mapsto v\otimes w$. Since identity clearly satisfies this, it follows that $\tilde\phi_2\tilde\phi_1=\id_{V\odot W}$. The same argument shows that $\tilde\phi_1\tilde\phi_2=\id_{W\odot V}$.

(Note that the conclusion does not make much sense in the non-commutative context - for $V\otimes_R W$ to make sense, we need $V$ to be a right $R$-module and $W$ to be a left $R$-module. The difference is that if $R$ is commutative, all left $R$-modules can be thought of as right $R$-modules with the same multiplication, which would, in general, violate mixed associativity.)